# Do we need to deploy ng-build every time we make changes to code

Tags: angular

I need an angular help

I have a  static Angular App as of now

I did **`ng build --prod --base-href 'my_url'`**

got **dist** folder uploaded it to the server and it loads template perfectly. (I mean I did settings for CSS, js and images that all worked)

Now the query is every time I'll work further on the App of-course to make it dynamic changing content Again I'll have to create a new disc folder and replace the previous one.

If this is the case then how can we maintain git for our project?

I mean what we do as of now for static project push code to git from local and pull on the server.

I think I am new to it and don't know the right way.

Comment: You'll want to git-ignore the dist folder (as well as node_modules).

Comment: No, I don't want to ignore dist folder.

I mean when I'll push from my local to git, of course, I need all files go to git except node_modules to retain the older versions of my code.

And to live server only dist folder is enough to run site.

SO the concept od CI/CD found to be missing.

What we push is not exactly what we will pull to our live server.

Comment: Yes, only the dist folder is used to run an Angular project.. Todarmal's answer is perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a static project, we can directly copy the files into the root folder (`/var/www`) on the server.

But in angular or any modern frameworks, we have to make a distribution folder (dist) which contains the compiled code.

For this, I follow the standard approach. I maintain a git repository with the uncompiled code.

Whenever you make changes, you need to create a dist folder and then upload it on the server. But it can be a tedious task.

So, CI/CD comes into the picture, which basically takes our code from the git repo and compiles it then with scripts, your code gets pushed to the root folder (`/var/www`) of your application on the server.

There are a lot of tools for implementing CI/CD. I personally use [jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) as it is more simpler to use.

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: You mean tools like Jenkins create disc folder only to the  (/var/html) rest of the folder like e2e and src will not come ?

Comment: Yes. For creating `dist` folder you need to run `ng build --prod --base-href 'my_url'` and for making it available to access from the internet you need to copy the contents of dist folder to `/va/html/`. These tasks can be automated with CI/CD tools like jenkins.